# FireBase once method behaves recursively

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dailog element and a function for it to get all comments and add them to comment section and a input with button to add a new comment
But when I click on button it recursively adds the comment unless I close browser
Html

```
<dialog id="reply">
<div id="replymain">
<button id="replyclose">×</button>
<div id="coms">
<div id="com">hello there</div>
</div>
<div id="send">
<input id="sendinput" placeholder="Message"  />
<button id="sendreply">+</button>
</div>
</div>
</dialog>
```

For adding all the comments

```
function comment(id){
localStorage.setItem("last",id)
reply.showModal()
firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).once("value",(snap) => {
const cs = snap.val().comments || []
console.log(cs)
cs.forEach(c => {
coms.innerHTML += `
<div id="com">${c}</div>
`
})
})
}
```

Button function

```
sendreply.onclick = () => {
addC(localStorage.getItem("last") , sendinput.value , true)
}
```

AddC function

```
function addC(id,c){
firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).once("value",(snap) => {
const cs = snap.val().comments || []
firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).update({
comments: [...cs,c]
})
})
}
```

***is there a way to fix it or do I have to forcefully cancel it with setTineout***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data only 'one time' using `.get()` and update the comments.

When you use `once("value")`, it registers a listener with a function that will be executed every time a value is added / updated.

```js
function addC(id, c) {
    firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).get().then((snap) => {
        const cs = snap.val().comments || []
        firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).update({
            comments: [...cs, c]
        })
    })
}
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events